# how to combine different frequence into one .wav

Tags: audio, matlab-figure

I want to creat a .wav from 12khz to 13khz by matlab.I know how to create a single frequence,but idont know how to combine them into one file.
Is there any simple command?

```matlab
Fs =44100;    
toneFreq1 = 12000; 
nSeconds = 25;  
f1 = sin(linspace(0, nSeconds*toneFreq1*2*pi, round(nSeconds*Fs)));
toneFreq2 = 12100; 
nSeconds = 25;  
f2 = sin(linspace(0, nSeconds*toneFreq2*2*pi, round(nSeconds*Fs)));
toneFreq3 = 12200; 
nSeconds = 25;  
f3 = sin(linspace(0, nSeconds*toneFreq3*2*pi, round(nSeconds*Fs)));
toneFreq4 = 12300; 
nSeconds = 25;  
f4 = sin(linspace(0, nSeconds*toneFreq4*2*pi, round(nSeconds*Fs)));
toneFreq5 = 12400; 
nSeconds = 25;  
f5 = sin(linspace(0, nSeconds*toneFreq5*2*pi, round(nSeconds*Fs)));
toneFreq6 = 12500; 
nSeconds = 25;  
f6 = sin(linspace(0, nSeconds*toneFreq6*2*pi, round(nSeconds*Fs)));
toneFreq7 = 12600; 
nSeconds = 25;  
f7 = sin(linspace(0, nSeconds*toneFreq7*2*pi, round(nSeconds*Fs)));
toneFreq8 = 12700; 
nSeconds = 25;  
f8 = sin(linspace(0, nSeconds*toneFreq8*2*pi, round(nSeconds*Fs)));
toneFreq9 = 12800; 
nSeconds = 25;  
f9 = sin(linspace(0, nSeconds*toneFreq9*2*pi, round(nSeconds*Fs)));
toneFreq10 = 12900; 
nSeconds = 25;  
f10 = sin(linspace(0, nSeconds*toneFreq10*2*pi, round(nSeconds*Fs)));


f_12345678910= [f1+f2+f3+f4+f5+f6+f7+f8+f9+f10];


f_z=[f_12345678910];
sound(f_z,Fs) 
wavwrite(f_z, Fs, 24, '12_13zKHz.wav');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data for wavwrite needs to be in the range of -1.0 to 1.0. You can fix this by dividing by 10.

```
f_12345678910= [f1+f2+f3+f4+f5+f6+f7+f8+f9+f10]/10;
```

Your sine wave generation would be more readable if you generate the time axis once.

```
t = [1:1:(Fs*nSeconds)];
f1 = sin(2*pi*t*toneFreq1/Fs);
```

Comment: To jaket; Thank you for your suggestion.It is so helpful for me. Thank you.

Comment: To Jaket, I can get the figure (which has a platform from 8khz to 16khz it is good), but i can also see some high frequency wave in the figure(about >20khz), can you have some idea to avoid them. Thank you.